# How to add more than one location path to django FileSystemStorage backend?

Tags: python, django, storage, models, backend

Im trying to create custom storage backend in Django==1.6.8 to make possible to decide where file passed to FileField should be saved in local storage depends on specified value from other field. I know that I can set location attribute of FileSystemStorage when it is initialized, but it's not works in my situation, it set the same path for all instances.
I think custom storage https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-file-storage/# is a good way for this.
The paths should be completely different, no subdirectory of MEDIA_ROOT, completely different absolute paths.

Can i simply override this FileSystemStorage method:

```
def path(self, name):
    try:
        path = safe_join(self.location, name)
    except ValueError:
        raise SuspiciousFileOperation("Attempted access to '%s' denied." % name)
    return os.path.normpath(path)
```

...somehow? Is it a good idea?
Please help!

Comment: Would you mind sharing the use case of having completely different absolute target directories? As you've mentioned the `location` attribute of `FileSystemStorage`  makes it possible to define an arbitrary path, but its base path cannot be changed dynamically ( `upload_to` can receive a callable and thus build a dynamic path below that base path, but it sounds like this is not enough for your use case).